# Parse CSV file with some dynamic columns

Tags: excel, parsing, csv

I have a CSV file that I receive once a week that is in the following format:

```
"Item","Supplier Item","Description","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ...Linefeed
"","","","Past Due","Day 13-OCT-2014","Buffer 14-OCT-2014","Week 20-OCT-2014","Week 27-OCT-2014", ...LineFeed
"Part1","P1","Big Part","0","0","0","100","50", ...LineFeed
"Part4","P4","Red Part","0","0","0","35","40", ...LineFeed
"Part92","P92","White Part","0","0","0","10","20", ...LineFeed
...
```

An explanation of the data - Row 2 is dynamic data signifying the date parts are due. Row 3 begins the part numbers with description and number of parts due on a particular date. So looking at the above data: row 3 column7 shows that PartNo1 has 100 parts due on the Week of OCT 20 2014 and 50 due on the Week of OCT 27, 2014.

How can I parse this csv to show the data like this:

```
Item,    Supplier Item, Description, Past Due, Due Date     Amount Due
Part1    P1             Big Part     0         20 OCT 2014  100
Part1    P1             Big Part     0         27 OCT 2014  50
Part4    P4             Red Part     0         20 OCT 2014  35
Part4    P4             Red Part     0         27 OCT 2014  40
```

....

Is there a way to manipulate the format in Excel to rearrange the data like I need or what is the best method to resolve this?

Comment: Seems like the best approach would be to import the csv to excel and then reformat it usingf a macro.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't done anything to it yet.  I am unsure of the best approach and how to precede.

Comment: Would text to columns be of any use?